# Why does strtok not work with stringstream?

Tags: c++, split, stringstream, strtok

Consider these parameters:

```
char words[8] = "one two";
string word1;
string word2;
stringstream ss;
```

The output of this code:

```
ss << strtok(words, " ");
ss >> word1;
ss << strtok(NULL, " ");
ss >> word2;
cout << "Words: " << word1 << " " << word2 << endl;
```

is:

```
Words: one
```

while for this code

```
ss << strtok(words, " ");
ss >> word1;
char* temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
word2 = temp;
cout << "Words: " << word1 << " " << word2 << endl;
```

the output is:

```
Words: one two
```

Why `stringstream` can handle the first returned value of `strtok` but not the second?

Comment: Just a guess. After you input the first word, the ostream portion of `ss` hits EOF and sets the `eof` flag. No further input is possible unless you clear that flag by hand.

Comment: It can handle all of them, but you're not using it correctly. You're trying to use `stringstream` as a container, but it is instead a _flow of data_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should insert statement

```
ss.clear();
```

that to clear the eof state of the stream. For example

```
    char words[8] = "one two";
    std::string word1;
    std::string word2;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::strtok(words, " ");
    ss >> word1;
    ss.clear();
    ss << std::strtok(NULL, " ");
    ss >> word2;
    std::cout << "Words: " << word1 << " " << word2 << std::endl;
```